# Is Code On The Timeline Easier Or Harder For Hackers To Steal/Decompile?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timeline, decompiling

Can anyone tell me whether code on the timeline is harder or easier to steal/decompile?
Or is it all just the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real difference. A dedicated programmer can always get to and reverse engineer your ActionScript. Bear in mind it's not just 3rd party apps like Sothink that can be used. Even Adobe have a tool for 'inspecting' a swf: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/swfinvestigator/.

If your code is genuinely special enough to warrant stealing, then you would want to use a platform other than Flash (or put your sensitive code into an external C/C++ assembly and run that using something like [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/)).

Are you really doing something so unique that people are going to try to steal it, though? Is it so special they couldn't just figure out what you've done and copy it?

Comment: Thank you,I will be looking into Alchemy and such programs,and yes,some of my code is special.But the main reason of this paranoia is because I'am currently making a long series of a game like SCGMD (though my series may not be so epic) and I don't want anyone to cut in.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is essentially nil. In AS3, timeline code will end up inside classes anyway. The code for the main timeline will appear in `*filename*_fla.MainTimeline`. The code for Symbol1 will appear in `*filename*_fla.Symbol1`, and so on.

Timeline code can be slightly easily to understand, since variables not explicitly declared as local variables will become class variables. The names of class variables are preserved in a SWF, whereas local variables are not.

Check out my [online ActionScript dissembler](http://flaczki.net46.net/codedump/) if you're curious about how your code is stored inside a SWF.